# Html-helper postLink in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, post, hyperlink, html-helper, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to create something like this as i have done it in one of my admin views:

```
<td class="actions">
    <form action="/users/delete/26" name="post_4f7825317b6b0" id="post_4f7825317b6b0" style="display:none;" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
    </form>
    <a href="#" onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete # 26?')) { document.post_4f7825317b6b0.submit(); } event.returnValue = false; return false;">
         Delete
    </a>
</td>
```

Using this:

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array(
                 'action' => 'delete', 
                 $user['User']['id']),
                 null,
                 __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $user['User']['id'])); 
?>
```

I am trying it with the same code in another view and i dont know why i only get this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
<a href="#" onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?')) { document.post_4f782a44e9784.submit(); } event.returnValue = false; return false;">
    Delete
</a>
```

Why is this happening if i am using the exact same code to generate it?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure `$user` variable is set and contains what you think it does?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You haven't created the form itself so essentially you are using input fields without a form.

```
echo $this->Form->create();
```

Comment: That is actually wrong. $this->Form->postLink() does not have to be inside a form. Actually it cannot be inside a form (See https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L1728).

Comment: This is so misleading... as @tinytiger pointed out, you CANNOT have a form within a form. This will break things.

Comment: This answer is categorically wrong and should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

First. Check CakePHP version.

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array(
                 'action' => 'delete', 
                 $user['User']['id']),
                ['inline' => true],
                 __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $user['User']['id'])); 
?>
```